# Laravel change request file input

Tags: php, file, laravel, input, request

I've been trying to modify the request to switch the uploaded file with the new moved one (I have to move it first to a temp with his audio extension so I can check it with **getID3**), so I could validate it with my `CustomAudioValidator` (using **getID3**, the default mimetypeguesser isn't good enough since sometimes it returns application/octet-stream).

The problem is using replace doesn't work, so I got deeper and found out that it was a mix of

`$request->files and $request->all()`

So I tried

```
$request->files->replace
```

But the `$request` still doesn't change and keeps having the first Uploaded File with an non-existant and `.tmp` extension (that I moved to a temp dir with whatever audio extension it had such as `mp3`);

Is there a way to change that request clearly or what other way do I have to bypass that ?

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('music')){
        $music = $request->file('music');
        $originalName = $music->getClientOriginalName();
        $localtempfilename = $music->move(public_path('uploads\tmp'), $originalName);
        $requestReplace = array('size' => intval($localtempfilename->getSize()/1000),
            'user' => Auth::user()->id,

        );
        $request->replace($requestReplace);
        $request->files->replace(array('music' => new UploadedFile($localtempfilename->getPathname(), $originalName) )); // $request is modified with new UploadedFile with correct paths
        $this->validate($request, Music::getRules()); //$request still uses old $music to validate and gives an error about file path inexistant since I moved it 
    }

}



class CustomAudioValidator {

    public function validateType($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
    {
        if (!($value instanceof UploadedFile)) return false;
        if ($fp_remote = fopen($value->getPathname(), 'rb')) {
            if ($fp_local = fopen($value->getPathname(), 'wb')) {
                while ($buffer = fread($fp_remote, 8192)) {
                    fwrite($fp_local, $buffer);
                }

                fclose($fp_local);
                // Initialize getID3 engine
                $getID3 = new getID3;
                $fileInfo = $getID3->analyze($value->getPathname());
            }
            fclose($fp_remote);
        }
        else throw(New FileNotFoundException($value->getPathname() . ' doesn\'t exist '));

        if (in_array( $fileInfo['mime_type'],
            ['audio/mpeg', 'audio/mp3', 'audio/wav', 'audio/xwav', 'audio/ogg']
            ))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            Storage::delete($value->getPathname());
        };
    }

}

public static function getRules() {
    return array(
        'user' => 'required|integer|max:255',
        'size' => 'required|integer|max:15360',
        'music' => 'required|max:15360|audio'
    );
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just validate uploaded file directly, instead of moving it to another folder?

Comment: @Skysplit It won't validate cause it still has .tmp extension and saved in "cache"

Comment: You can use `file|mimetypes:audio/mpeg,audio/mp3,audio/wav,audio/xwav,audio/ogg|your_validator` and skip mimes validation in your validator. Also, looking at getid3 docs, I do not see it is dependent on file extension, so reading it directly from tmp file should do the job

Comment: @Skysplit why would I use your_validator and then skip mimes validation and I tried on tmp files it just doesn't work

Comment: Can you show me your validation rules?

Comment: @Skysplit that's really not the problem...